# Python Program to check if a number is armstrong or not is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

```
n=int(input("Enter a Number: "))
x=0
y=0
z=0

while(n>0):
    x=n%10
    y=x**3
    z=z+y
    n=n//10

print (z) 


#The z here is the same value which I enter, yet it doesn't work.
#If I enter 407 as n, z becomes (4^3)+(0^3)+(7^3) which is 407

 if (z==n): 

#But even when 407==407, it just wont print the bottom statement


    print ("The number is Armstrong")
else:
    print ("The number isn't Armstrong")
 #it prints that it isn't an Armstrong number
```

Comment: Because, `n` is changed after the loop and it can't be equal to `z`.

Answer (score 1):

After the `while` loop, `n` already became `4//10` which is `0`, so it'll never equal `z` which is 407.

You will want to keep a copy of the original input for comparison.

As a general advice, use a debugger or at least `print()` your objects to see where the assignments went wrong.

Comment: But I did **print** **(x)** and the value is same as the entered n.

Comment: The problem is not `x`, it's `n` because in each loop you altered its value, and at the end you will always end up with `0`.  You can easily see this by adding a `print(n)` at the end of each loop.

Answer (score 1):

**Without using any built-in method**

Armstrong number is `371` because `3**3 + 7**3 + 1**3 = 371`. according this rule `123` is not Armstrong number because `1**3 + 2**3 + 3**3 is not equal to 123`

```
def count_digit(n):
    count = 0
    while n > 0:
        count += 1
        n //= 10
    return count

def is_armstrong(n):
    given = n
    result = 0
    digit = count_digit(n)
    while n > 0:
        reminder = n % 10
        result += reminder ** digit
        n //= 10 
    return given == result
```

```
is_armstrong(371)
>> True

is_armstrong(123)
>> False
```

Answer (score 0):

Definition: a number `n` is an [Armstrong number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) if the sum of each digit in `n` taken to the power of the total digits in `n` is equal to `n`.

It's important to keep track of the original number `n`, because it'll be needed to compare against the result of `z` (your variable representing the sum). Since you're mutating `n` in your `while` loop, there's no grounds for comparison against your original input, so `if (z==n):` isn't working like you expect. Save `n` in another variable, say, `original`, before reducing it to 0.

Additionally, your code has arbitrarily chosen 3 as the number of digits in the number. For your function to work correctly for any number, you'll need a way to count its digits. One way is to convert the number to a string and take the length.

I strongly recommend using descriptive variable names which reduces the chance of confusing yourself and others. It's only apparent that `z` represents your sum and `x` your remainder by virtue of reading through the code. If the code was any longer or more complex, it could be a nightmare to make sense of.

Lastly, Python is not a particularly flexible language from a style standpoint. I recommend adhering to the [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) as best as possible to keep your code readable.

Here's a working example:

```
def armstrong(n):
    total = 0
    original = n
    digits = len(str(n))

    while n > 0:
        total += (n % 10) ** digits
        n //= 10

    return total == original


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while 1:
        print(armstrong(int(input("Enter a Number: "))))
```

Output:

```
Enter a Number:  407
True
Enter a Number:  1234
False
Enter a Number:  23
False
Enter a Number:  8
True
Enter a Number:  371
True
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/FuzzyCurvyCollaborativesoftware)

Answer (score 0):

You can take in your initial number as a string so we can more easily convert it to a list. We can then `map` to create that list of `ints`. After we can use list comprehension to raise all `int` in that list to the power that is the `len` of our list.  If the `sum` of this list equals our input, then we have an Armstrong number.

```
n = input('Enter a number: ')
nums = list(map(int, n))
raised = [i**len(nums) for i in nums]
if sum(raised) == int(n):
    print('The number is Armstrong')
else:
    print('The number is not Armstrong')
```

Expanded list comprehension:

```
raised = []
for i in nums:
    i = i**len(nums)
    raised.append(i)
print(raised)
```

Alternate for `map`:

```
nums = []
for i in n:
    i = int(i)
    nums.append(int(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your code:

```
n = int(input("Enter a Number: "))
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
num = n
while n > 0:
    x = n % 10
    y = x**len(str(num))
    z = z+y
    n = n//10

print(z)
if (z == num):
    print ("The number is Armstrong")
else:
    print ("The number isn't Armstrong")
```

But you can still do it in many ways better. Look at the code of [vash_the_stampede](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52789444/10646189) and [ggorlen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52789257/10646189).

Or:

```
def isArmstrong(n):
    print(f"{n} is {'' if int(n) == sum(int(i)**len(n) for i in n) else 'not '}an Armstrong number")

isArmstrong(input("Please enter a number: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
total=0

def Armstrong(n):
    m=list(n)
    global total
    for i in m:
        total+=pow(int(i),len(n))
    if total==int(n):
        print ("it is Armstrong number")
    else:
        print("it is not Armstrong number")

Armstrong(input("enter your number"))
print(total)
```

Comment: You should be more specific!