# Narcissistic numbers in Python

Tags: python, function

I am beginner to the Python programming language and I have been using a website to help me exercise. It gave me this challenge to make a program that returns true if a given number is [narcissistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) or false otherwise.

Examples of narcissistic numbers:

```
153 (3 digits): 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 1 + 125 + 27 = 153
1634 (4 digits): 1^4 + 6^4 + 3^4 + 4^4 = 1 + 1296 + 81 + 256 = 1634
```

But for some reason when the number `371` is given the function returns `False` instead of `True`.

The code:

```
def narcissistic(value):
    logical = True
    logical2 = True
    i = 0
    j = 0
    notation = 10
    sum = 0

    #Calculating the number notation 
    while logical:
        if 10 ** i <= value:
            notation = 10 ** i
            i = i + 1
        else:
            logical = False

    #i from now on is also the qauntity of digits
    while logical2:
        if ( notation / 10 ** j ) >= 1:
            sum = sum + ( value // ( notation / 10 ** j ) ) ** i
            j = j + 1
        else:
            logical2 = False

    if sum == value:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: What is a narcissistic number?

Comment: @Hippolippo Re-read the question - the edit makes it clearer.

Comment: btw your algorithm might be better if you converted the number to a string and did a calculation with the digits.

Comment: This Wolfram link http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NarcissisticNumber.html starts talking about base-10 numbers, as is the OP.

Comment: Welcome to SO! [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52789257/6243352) might help you. Basically, the logic here is quite difficult to follow--lots of extra variables with unclear names and flags. I recommend [walking through your logic step-by-step](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to determine where your assumptions have gone wrong. The branch that ultimately returns false is the last one, so your digit counting appears fine, if that gives a hint.

Comment: The narcissistic number for x would be `sum([int(d)**len(x) for d in str(x)])` so then just compare them

Comment: Don't name your variable *sum*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is very close! The issue lies here:

`sum = sum + ( value // ( notation / 10 ** j ) ) ** i`

For `1634`, this multiplies `1`, `16`, `163`, and `1634`. You need only the LSB of these numbers, in this example `1`, `6`, `3`, and `4` - use the modulo operator to get this. If we mod them by 10 to get only the LSB...

`sum = sum + (( value // ( notation / 10 ** j ) ) % 10) ** i`

...then the code works perfectly.

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/SteepUnimportantKernelmode)

Answer (score 4):

It would probably be easier to do this task by converting the value to a string and back. Taking the length of the string is an easy way to get the number of digits ("the poor man's logarithm"), and you can easily iterate over individual digits:

```
def narcissistic(value):
    str_value = str(value)
    num_digits = len(str_value)
    return (value == sum(int(digit) ** num_digits for digit in str_value))
```

```
>>> narcissistic(153)
True
>>> narcissistic(1634)
True
>>> narcissistic(371)
True
>>> narcissistic(372)
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Could grab individual digits without converting to string

```
import math
def narcissistic(value):
    n = math.floor(math.log10(value)) + 1
    x = [math.floor((value/10**i)%10)**n for i in range(n)]   
    print(sum(x) == value)

narcissistic(371)
#True
```

Comment: Even if I too prefer working with math operations when it comes to (integer) numbers, in *Python* it's faster working with strings.

Answer (score 0):

change ^ to **

```
def narcissistic(number):
  number_string = str(number)
  number_len = len(number_string)

  number_nar = 0
  for char in number_string:
    number_nar+= int(char) ** number_len        
  return number_nar

number = 153
number_nar = narcissistic(number)
print(number_nar)

number = 1634
number_nar = narcissistic(number)
print(number_nar)
```

output:

```
153

1634
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using list comprehension in 1 line of code.

```
def Narcissistic(x):
        y = sum([int(i)**(len(x)) for i in (x)])
return Narcissistic(x)
```